# Adding divs inside a hidden section

Tags: html, css, hidden

I have 8 hidden sections with `display:none;` on my site that are triggered with `jQuery` to show when a `select` id is selected. When i try to start building the structure inside the hidden element #Restaurant (like this)

```
<div id="common">           

    <div id="Restaurant" class="common_reveal">

                            <div class="common_title">test</div>

   </div>       
</div>
```

It doesn't work. However, if i just insert plain text or `<span>`, it does...

Is there a reason for why it wont display additional `<div>`'s within the hidden element?

JS

```
$('#business_type').change(function(){
   $("#common div").each(function() {
       $(this).attr("style", "display: none;");
   })
   $("#" + $(this).val()).attr("style", "display: block;");
})
```

CSS

```
#common {
}
.common_reveal {display: none;}
```

Comment: Please show a bit more code. How can I possibly find the problem with the JS if you haven't even showed the JS.

Comment: Please provide the additional code (javascript) as it is unclear how to answer this question without it.

Comment: If the element is hidden, why do you expected for elements inside it to be displayed?

Comment: JS is missing a `;` at the end of the 2 `})`. I imagine that is just part of your editing atm though.

Comment: I want the relevent hidden element and its contents to be displayed when the releent select ID is selected.

Comment: displaying a hidden element when its select ID is selected from a select menu. I have managed to do that but when i try and build inside the element with further div structures, it runs nothing inside the element.

Comment: try for first level child alone `$("#common > div")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are picking all divs inside your #common element, try this:

`$("#common >div").each(...)`

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you.

Comment: @TheGuest because you are not adding your `display:none` via javascript . You add it inline and you are showing the div on click, removing the `display:none`